# what are the possible exceptions for parsing a config or xml file?

Tags: c++

**How do you handle all possible exceptions in parsing a file?**

My code has an abstract base class and two derived classes (XML and config) based on type of file I have written code for parsing.

Comment: Please post some code showing a sample case of your problem.

Comment: @holtavolt: Its a design question more than a coding question.

Comment: Not completely - I was wondering if he was using already using std and/or any other frameworks.  I like your answer (upvoted), but it does assume std.

Answer (score 2):

I would just have one exception:

```
#include <stdexcept>

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class ParserException: public std::runtime_error
    {
        public:
            ParserException(std::string const& msg)
                : runtime_error(msg)
            {}
    };
};
```

If there is a problem just throw ParserException with an appropriate error msg. If there is a particular situation where it is easy and conceivable a user would actually recover from then create a specific exception for this situation (derived from ParserException).

- **Do not** Create a new exception class for each and every error.
- If you do create more exceptions for parser. Then derive them from ParserException, so that they can potentially all be handled as a group.
- If something generic happens. Use one of the standard exceptions.

Usage:

```
if (bad)
{   throw ParserException("Something Bad Happened");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be lots of exceptions, many of which may be unlikely to occur, but obvious ones might be:-

- No data in the file (failed to load for whatever reason)
- Invalid XML
- Unexpected format of data (though this should be handled by proper parsing)
- Illegal characters in XML (not escaped properly)
- Extended Unicode characters in data (should be handled gracefully in parsing)
- Parser runs out of memory

That's a start...!